# apns push notification click check

Tags: php, safari, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented a PHP server which sends push notifications to visitors of my site with the following code:

```
    $streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'mypass');
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $streamContext);
$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $T)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
$fwriter = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
```

Everything is working fine but I want to see if the users click on my notifications or just dont pay attention to them, and hence count how many notifications get clicked. Any ideas how to do that? I think that it should be done via php streams with something like this:

```
stream_context_set_params($streamContext, array('notification' => 'callback'));
```

but I see nothing when my notification is clicked. Maybe there is any way how to receive a feedback from a stream and call a particular PHP function? Would appreciate any help. Thank You.